# PayPal IPN Script not Redirecting to ipn.php

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have downloaded the sample paypal IPN script using php and customised with the email for the buyout option and it has also some hidden paramaters such amount, quantity,return_url, notify_url like this.After the success payment in the sandbox url,it doesn't redirect to the ipn.php to make database insertion for successful transaction.

My site url: http://anderson.000space.com/paypal_ipn/example-form.html

I  have given the notify url for IPN  in my paypal sandbox merchant account as http://anderson.000space.com/paypal_ipn/ipn.php. I have printed some values there and given exit in that page, but the redirection from paypal is not going to ipn.php.

Answer (score 1):

IPN is not the redirection page. "return"  controls which page they're redirected back to, "notify_url" (IPN) is the script that receives a POST from PayPal with transaction information.

Comment: sorry i was new to paypal_ipn so only its confusing...Even i have given the controls like this , but its not redirecting .      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://anderson.000space.com/paypal_ipn/ipn.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://anderson.000space.com/paypal_ipn/example-form.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://anderson.000space.com/paypal_ipn/ipn.php" />